# Why are my strings not printing correctly in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a simple program as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;
    cout << "Enter N: " << endl;
    cin >> N;
    int acc = 0;

    cin >> acc;
    int min = acc;
    int max = acc;


    for (int i=1; i<N; i++) {
        int current;
        cin >> current;
        acc += current;
        if (current > max) {
            max = current;
        } else if (current < min) {
            min = current;
        }
    }

    cout << "Total: " + acc << endl;
    cout << "Max: " + max << endl;
    cout << "Min: " + min << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My output is getting chopped off as follows

```
./stat
Enter N:
3
1
2
3

:
in:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, the operator `+` on a string and a number behaves differently than you might expect from higher level languages.

"Total: " for instance is a character array, and if `a[10]` is your array, `a + 5` is the slice of the array starting at `a[5]`. This is known as [pointer arithmetic](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html).

"Total: " is represented in memory as 'T' 'o' 't' 'a' 'l' ':' ' ' 0, so "Total : " + 4 is 'l' ':' ' ' 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
cout << "Total: " << acc << endl;
cout << "Max: " << max << endl;
cout << "Min: " << min << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your output lines to:

```
cout << "Total: " << acc << endl;
```

Use the << operator instead of +.